# Does this make sense

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences

Does saying, 'I've been here for a shorter period of time' make sense or 'shorter time than you'? Like, I know, 'I've been here longer than you' makes sense but I'm not sure about the first example.

Comment: I haven’t been here as long as you have.

Comment: I think you can say either of those, but why not *I haven't been here as long as you*?

Comment: You arrived before me. You were already here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not colloquial to say, *I've been here a shorter time than you.* It would be better to say something such as: *I arrived/came after you* or *You've been here longer than me*.

Comment: Please never use code markup here. We do not use computer code in many if our answers. Just set in italic or use proper quotes.